# Multiple Fields Indexed Object Array

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, in-memory-database

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have 100k users.

Query: Get Users Whose Name is "Rafael" AND  whose age is between 40 and 50

- By Linq2Objects : users.Where(p=>p. Name=="Rafael" &&  p.Age>=40 && p.Age<=50).ToArray();

Is there any  alternative implemantation with better performance? (Readonly Thread-Safe)

(MultiIndexed User Array)

I've tested it's performance. For 1000k users it takes 30-50 ms. It seems not important but it is.
Because I can get 50 requests in a second.

With dharnitski's solution. It takes 0ms. :)

But is there any code framework makes it transparently.

```
public  class   FastArray<T>
```

Comment: By thread-safe, do you mean that there will be other processes writing to your collection while you query from it?

Comment: No sorry. ReadOnly ThreadSafe. I 've updated question.

Comment: _But is there any code framework makes it transparently._ - Yes. It is RDBMS :)

Comment: Check also http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get result you want without full dataset scan if your data is not prepared.
Prepare data in advance when time is not critical and work with sorted data when you need short response time.

There is an analogy for this in database world.

*There is a table with 100K records. Somebody wants to run a Select query with "where" clause that filter data by not primary key. It always will be slow "table scan" operation in execution plan unless index(es) is implemented.*

Sample of code that implements indexing using [`ILookup<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx):

```
//not sorted array of users - raw data
User[] originalUsers;
//Prepare data in advance (create one index). 
//Field with the best distribution should be used as key
ILookup<string, User> preparedUsers = originalUsers.ToLookup(u => u.Name, u => u);


//run this code when you need subset 
//search by key is optimized by .NET class 
//"where" clause works with small set of data
preparedUsers["Rafael"].Where(p=> p.Age>=40 && p.Age<=50).ToArray();
```

This code is not as powerful as database indexes (for example it does not support substrings) but it shows the idea.